# Google Analytics event recorded but not converted in goal

Tags: google-analytics

Scenario: I have 2 websites A and B and I want to track whenever a user from A clicks on a link that leads to B, and consider that a goal.

Solution: To do so I am able to create an event [as per docs](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en). I even modified the thing so that it's a bit nicer (it does not label the event as the url but gives a decent label). Anyways, here are the events properly recorded:

[image]

So now I configure the goal to listen events, and then in detail I have:
[image]

[EDIT, right spelling of outbound now]

As you can see the conversion rate is 0%. As you can see we have the proper category, action and label. I also tried the "starts with" in the label to no avail.

As you can also see there is no value, as the code I use to send the event is the following:

```
            var trackOutboundLink = function(label) {
           ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', label, {
             'transport': 'beacon',
             'hitCallback': function(){/*document.location = url;*/}
           });
        }
```

you will note that the callback is an empty function because I process directly the href of the link. In any case even with the standard configuration (copy paste of the code from GA which sets the url as label) it did not work.

Any clue?

Thank you!

SN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You spelt outbound wrong in the Goal Details

Comment: Nice catch! Unfortunately it does not make any difference after fixing it :( I tried so many times this thing, several times using copy and paste, that's why I ruled out typos. I edited the post with the new picture and added an EDIT

Comment: Nevermind. I don't know what happened here, but now I'm seeing the estimated conversion on the last 7 days as 1.64%. But when I return to the goal page I still see 0 over the last 7 days (yes, I refreshed the page)

Comment: Today I see them. Must have been a problem of daily refresh of data. Thank you

Comment: @SergioNegri it was probably caching the mistake